# postman post request json payload created and in return , response is empty with respect to spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**** **I have created repository and autowired that to service class and created controller
and autowired the service and and the sample code below same code i have tried it for
different project and it is working but in this seems to be an issue please someone
help me solve this**..**

```
Thank you.
```

---

```
payload request:

  {
     "name":"john",
     "gender":"male",
     "guardianName":"jackson"
  }

  the response 

  []
```

---

**Controller class **

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/patients")
  public class PatientsController {

    @Autowired
    private PatientsService patientsService;

    
    public PatientsController(PatientsService patientsService)
    {
        this.patientsService = patientsService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Patients> findAllPatients() {
        return patientsService.findAllPatients();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Patients> findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return patientsService.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Patients savePatient(@RequestBody Patients patients) {
        return patientsService.savePatients(patients);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public Patients updateEmployee(@RequestBody Patients patients`enter code here`) {
        return patientsService.updatePatients(patients);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        patientsService.deleteEmployee(id);
      }
  }
```

---

**domain simple pojo class**

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "patient")
  public class Patients {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NonNull
    private long id;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "guardian_Name")
    private String guardianName;
 
    public Patients() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
 
    public Patients(String name, String gender, String guardianName) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.guardianName = guardianName;
    }
 



**
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for the above problem its nothing but in entity class forgot to add the "to String" method and parameter constructor

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).